# The order of names in Contacts app

Tags: contacts

I try to understand how the contacts are sorted in the Contacts app. I use Contacts on Mac and I don't have iPhone, but I think there should be no difference. I'm Russian (sorry about the war, I don't support president Putin) and therefore the contacts are named in Russian. The order of letters in the Russian alphabet is the following:

```
Аа Дд Ии Мм Нн Тт Яя
```

And the contacts themselves (which are sorted by last names currently) are listed in the following order:

```
Илья          first name only
Никита        first name only
Тимофей       first name only
Ярослав       first name only
Дмитрий А...  first and last names
Александр     first name only
Михаил Д...   first and last names
```

This doesn't make sense to me.

What I have expected instead is either:

```
Александр
Илья
Никита
Тимофей
Ярослав
Дмитрий А...
Михаил Д...

(fist all the contacts with first name only,
then all the contacts with both first and last names)
```

or maybe

```
Александр
Дмитрий А...
Михаил Д...
Илья
Никита
Тимофей
Ярослав

(if only the first name is specified, the contact is listed
by the first letter of the first name;
otherwise, the first letter of the last name is used)
```

So what is going on?

Edit: And here is how the names are listed in English. Same issue.

```
Ilya
Nikita
Timofey
Yaroslav
Dmitriy A...
Aleksandr
Mikhail D...
```

Comment: Why don't you set "Sort by" to first name? Last name doesn't make sense if majority of your contacts lack it.

Comment: Because most of my contacts don't lack the last name and this example is simply no more than just an example. Do I really need to specify it explicitly rather than implicitly that I simply want to understand why sorting order is so weird and my interest is completely irrespective to whether I prefer to sort by first or by last names?

Comment: I think that yes, you should implicitly state that you want to understand how sorting works. In order to understand one must have correct assumptions. For example, alphabet is written letters representing units of sound that distinguish words, therefore   `Аа Дд Ии Мм Нн Тт Яя` isin't an alphabet (neither for humans or computers). For debugging the problem one can start with sorting by first name. Does this delivers expected results? Of course it would be reasonable to check "Language & Region" settings, foremost "Preferred Languages" and "List sort order"